# Entity Framework database first on dll strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, dll

I have a remote SQL Server database, wrapped with Entity Framework inside a dll.
When I reference that dll from my main application, I get a runtime exception stating "missing connection string in app.settings file" or, if I manually add the connection string, "no Entity Framework engine found".
If instead, I install EF from NuGet ALSO in my main application, the referenced dll works perfectly.

Now, the reason why I created and referenced the dll was to detach my business layer from the persistence layer, but if I need anyway a reference to EF for my application to work, I'm loosing the advantage of the dll wrapping.

What should I do?

EDIT:
I can't add a dependency from my main app to EF simply because the user of that dll will be a client outside .NET, such as an Excel or Matlab instace

Comment: Did you publish application and install on remote machine?   A compiled VS will only work if the same version of Net is on the remote machine as the one you compiled on.  A publish will install missing windows libraries (Net) that are missing on remote machine.  Publish generates a setup folder just like commercial software which is needed for applications to work on other machines.

Comment: Can you please confirm that "no Entity Framework engine found" is the exact error message? If not, please post the exact error message. Also, copying a single .dll which references EF will not be callable unless the EF dll. files are also present and available to the process which needs to use them. I don't think Switching ORM's will address the issue.

Comment: Well, first of all let's say that I'm simply working on my local machine. My main app references the wrapping dll (wrap.dll) and nothing more. wrap.dll references EF, JSON and other dlls. All the connection strings are contained inside wrap.dll's app.config file. As a result, running my app, I get `Additional information: No connection string named 'mystring' could be found in the application config file`.

Comment: If I copy the connection string to my main app's app.config file, and I run again, I get `error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

Comment: I think the problem is that my CustomDbContext inherits from DbContext, which is defined inside EF package. Hence apparently my main app should reference EF as well, but I definitely want to avoid that. I also tried to embed EF inside my dll, but it seems impossible...

Comment: Do you know any smart idea to wrap DbContext type without depending from EF?

Comment: Yes, a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have the same issue with all your dependencies.  You must distribute multiple DLLs and make sure they get loaded.  See

See [Resolving Assembly Loads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/resolve-assembly-loads)

The AssemblyLoad event allows you to take over the assembly loading process for your AppDomain, and you can find the dependent assemblies on disk outside of the normal search locations (which are dependent on the host .exe location), or download them, or unpack them from assembly resources in your main .dll.

See also [How to load an Assembly in a SSIS script task that isn’t in the GAC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/)

Answer (score 0):

The dll NEVER has it's own config file that it accesses to read settings such as connection strings. Although your code to read the config information may be in an assembly, the config file is owned by the host process, so an entry for connection strings MUST be present in the Host processes config file.

In your scenario, it sounds like on the remote sever it will be SQL server that acts as the host process.  On your local machine, the host process (your .exe or website, IIS Wp3 ) will act as the host process. Your local process **WILL** require the connectionstring setting in web.config / app/config.

In VS, when we add a reference to an assembly project, all of the dependent .dll's get compiled and placed in the top level applications bin folder. If you simply reference a .dll file from your application, these dependent .dll files are not placed in the bin folder. This is what you are experiencing here with EF.

It is possible to encapsulate EF functionality inside a .dll file, but the .dll files which make up EF itself, **MUST** be available to the host process. You don't need to add a NuGet reference to your main application. By referencing the project that you .dll is built from in your main application, the EF engine will be compiled to the bin folder of your main application.

Once you have built and deployed your main application with a project reference to your assembly, all the required files will be in the folder from which you execute your application. You can then make changes to the .dll source and just update the .dll binaries in the application folder, providing the changes do not break contracts etc eg. method signatures.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but actually I have a slightly different problem. Assuming the issue related to the connection string is solved (eg. hard coded inside the dll), I still need to create a dll to be used from excel and matlab, not within the .NET world. In detail, I need to manipulate data from excel or matlab, add some computation and store the results inside a remote SQL Server database (and the other way round). To achieve my target, I decided to use EF inside my dll for what the interaction with the database is concerned. Hence, when distributing the dll, it must work as a standalone library.